# Segue performing in story

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have three ViewControllers. In first I open thirdViewController and in thirdViewController I open secondViewController. I use segue to perform seondViewController, but id doesn't work.

```
#import "thirdViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "secondViewController.h"


@interface thirdViewController (){
NSDictionary *currencies;
NSMutableArray *arrayCurrenciesKeys;
NSMutableData *webData;
NSURLConnection *connection ;
NSMutableArray *array;
NSMutableArray *temp;

}
@end


@implementation thirdViewController
@synthesize tableView,cityname;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.title=@"Типи валют";
[[self tableView]setDelegate:self];
[[self tableView]setDataSource:self];
array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      NSURL *url =[NSURL    URLWithString:@"http:resources.finance.ua/ua/public/currency-cash.json"];
NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
connection= [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(connection)
{
    webData=[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}


   tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
   tableView.alpha=0.9;



   }

   -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
    return 1;
   }
   -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:       (NSInteger)section
   {
   return [array count];
    }
   -(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";                                UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if(!cell)
  {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }

   cell.textLabel.text=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   return cell;
 }


    -(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 {
  [webData setLength:0];

  }
  -(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
   {
   [webData appendData:data];
   }
  -(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
   {
     NSLog(@"Error");
    }
   -(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
   {

   NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization   JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
NSDictionary *feed =[allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"organizations";

   for(NSDictionary *diction1 in feed){


   NSString *label1 = [diction1 objectForKey:@"cityId"];
   [temp addObject:label1];
   NSString *label2 =[[allDataDictionary objectForKey: @"cities" ] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",label1]];
   if(![array containsObject:label2]){
       [array addObject:label2];}
   else{
       ;
   }

[[self tableView]reloadData];
   }

 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Banks" sender:self];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Banks"])     {

}
 }




 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
 @end
```

Also i add segue identificator in the storyboard. I also try to present it with navigation controller,but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Does it give any error ? If yes then post the error logs also.

Comment: How are you going from the first controller to the third? Are you using a segue, or doing it in code. If in code, add that to your question.

Comment: I would recommend you to format your code!

Answer (score 1):

> I have three ViewControllers. In first I open thirdViewController and in thirdViewController I open secondViewController. I use segue to perform seondViewController, but id doesn't work.

I assume that your "first" is ViewController.h

1- Are you sure that the identifier of the segue from thirdViewController to secondViewController is @"Banks"?

You can be misleading it with the identifier of the segue from ViewController to thirdViewController.

2- Double check that you have the exact same string in Interface Builder and in code.

It can be @"Bankss" in Interface Builder and can be @"Banks" in code.